# Where does my embedded python stdout go?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-embedding

Consider the following [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Test 1\n");
  Py_Initialize();
  printf("Test 2\n");
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('Test 3')");
  printf("Test 4\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this as normal i get the expected output:

```
$ ./test
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 4
```

But when I redirect the output I get nothing from the python code:

```
$ ./test | cat
Test 1
Test 2
Test 4
```

What is happening? And more importantly how do I get my python output written to stdout like expected?

Comment: Interesting that if you add `'import sys; sys.stdout.flush()'` to the Python script, you get the redirected output, but _before_ everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `stdout` refers to a terminal, the output is line buffered otherwise which is block or fully buffered, won't output until the block is full.

To make the output line buffered when `stdout` refers to non-terminal, set the mode with [setvbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf)
And you have to call `Py_Finalize()` to have `libpython` close its I/O handle.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //setlinebuf(stdout);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
    printf("Test 1\n");
    Py_Initialize();
    printf("Test 2\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Test 3')");
    Py_Finalize();
    printf("Test 4\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can call `sys.stdout.flush()` in Python. Calling `Py_Finalize()` might not be intenional for his use case.

Comment: @tynn if you don't call `Py_Finalize()` the output is out of order, that's Python's is first.

Comment: Ah... of course, it all seams so obvious now :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In current Python, you can use `Py_UnbufferedStdioFlag`.